# Minus signs vanish with listings and breqn - any solutions?

Tags: listings, breqn

When using `listings` and `breqn`, the minus signs (or dashes, according to the unix.SX site then there's some controversy about which it is) disappear from code listing.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\lstset{language=Perl}
\begin{lstlisting}
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^-/) {
    print "Option given";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

with result:

[image: listings and breqn]

Changing the order of package loading doesn't help.  `breqn` does warn that it might break other packages, but it would be really useful to have both working.  If it helps, the code listings are in appendices so happen after the equations which `breqn` is meant to help with so I can happily reset anything that got changed.

Comment: Andrew reverse order worked for me.

Comment: @Yiannis: that's strange, it doesn't for me.  I'm compiling with `pdflatex` using the default packages from TeXLive 2010.

Comment: It doesn't even compile with TeXLive 2009 (as packaged on ubuntu).

Comment: Reverse order doesn't work for me (`pdflatex`, updated MiKTeX 2.8).

Comment: @Harald: what goes wrong on TL2009??

Comment: @Andrew: It begins with “Missing number, treated as zero” (while loading `listings.sty`) and goes downhill from there. I didn't have the time nor inclination to find out more, but just moved to my Mac (which has TL2010) instead.

Comment: I get regular minus signs.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example. Your choice of document class and preamble may affect your results, so don't leave them out.

Comment: Make it into a single example, not these sniplets (single example make it s alot easier for others to help)

Comment: Erh, the image you are showing does not match your example above. Please don't waste our time like this. But I see your problem.

Comment: It is caused by `breqn`, they come back when `breqn` is removed. In general, `breqn` should not be used. `breqn` messes with a lot of things, and if you notive when `breqn` is not used those are not being typeset as hyphens but rather as real math minuses, and `breqn` messes with those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `\lstlisting` likes to typeset a hypen-minus as `$-$`, and the the `breqn` package plays around with math so much. In particular, it sets the mathcode of the minus to `"8000`, which makes it active and seems to break things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\mathchardef\hyphenmathcode=\mathcode`\-
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{listings}

\let\origlstlisting=\lstlisting
\let\endoriglstlisting=\endlstlisting
\renewenvironment{lstlisting}
    {\mathcode`\-=\hyphenmathcode
     \everymath{}\mathsurround=0pt\origlstlisting}
    {\endoriglstlisting}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Perl}
\everymath{}
\begin{lstlisting}
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^-/) {
    print "Option given";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

(The `\everymath{}\mathsurround` is not necessary for this, but it should be there for good measure.)

**Edit:** Added the mathcode bit. I'll say more on this edit in the comments.

Comment: I just noticed that the `lstlisting` environment takes an optional parameter. If you want to support that, you may need a slightly more sophisticated redefinition.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this tomorrow and report back.  (Actually, I'm using the `\lstinputlisting` command since it's a "live program" but I reckon I can figure out how to hack that from your hack.)

Comment: Nope, this isn't working for me.

Comment: How bizarre! Now, my first fix is no longer working for me either. But I am sure it did, last night? I must have been doing something slightly different so as to avoid triggering the problem. Anyhow, from a joint session with Andrew we found that the mathcode of `-` is getting changed, and changing it back to its normal (non-active) meaning cures the disease. For now.

Comment: I'd simply use ``\preto{\lstlisting}{\mathcode`\=\hyphenmathcode}`` (after loading `etoolbox`). I wouldn't be surprised if other quirks like this one pop out. In my opinion `breqn` makes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 5):

By default listings uses a math minus here and this clashes with breqn. You can change the symbol listings uses for the hyphen. For example this uses \textminus and will work also with breqn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}


\lstinline +ABC-ABC+ 

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textminus}% used with ttfamily 
         \textminus}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\lstinline +ABC-ABC+

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\lstinline +ABC-ABC+

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer should go in the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: @egreg I will copy it. But I think I can't delete here if it is accepted?

Comment: I flagged to do a merge.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\normalfont

\makeatletter
\texttt{\meaning\lst@InputCatcodes\relax}
\makeatother

\lstset{language=Perl,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^(*@-@*)/) {
    print "Option given";
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It is really a font problem. The - sign in your font is an active character in listings. (See the `meaning`). If you escape it though it gets the right `catcode` and the error disappears. You escape using funny eyes:)
`(*@ @*)` and you can insert anything you want. Perhaps someone else can come with an easier solution as I guess it is a hassle to have to escape the sign always.

I use MikTeX for compiling.

**Edit**

Another hack would be to define a new environment using the `listings` `lstnewenvironment` command to protect the definitions from other packages:

```
\lstnewenvironment{perl}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=Perl}\lstset{%
   #1
}}
{}
```

This also worked,

Use:  `\begin{perl}...\end{perl}`

This solution is very similar to that given by Harald.

Comment: Escaping isn't an option as I'm actually importing a "live" program via the `\lstinputlisting` so adding the escapes every time would be a real hassle.  The other solution looks promising, thanks.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Also, I don't see where listings makes `-` active in that `meaning` string.

Comment: I'm also unable to use the "Another hack" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any minus operator (`-`) I had in my code sample under `lstlisting` was not showing up. I would get an "**Undefined control sequence. n--**" error.

[image: Code before, missing minuses]

For whatever reason, this fixed it (it'll shows a big dash but that'll do it for a quick solution):

1- Adding the package `minted` (without using it):

```
\usepackage{minted}
```

2- Invoking LaTeX with the `-shell-escape flag` at each build.

Following the steps mentioned [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99476/214109) by hpesoj626:

In TeXstudio

> Options > Configure TeXStudio > Build
>
> in the **User Commands** box, click <kbd>+Add</kbd> button and add a name for your command in the first cell, say `pdflatex -shell-escape` and the command `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` in the second cell.
>
> You can then see the command listed in the menu
>
> Tools > User
>
> Click on the command to run.

When I ran my code the minuses in the `lstlisting` sections showed up.

[image: Code after, showing minuses]