# Minus sign disappears in lstlisting if I import the semantic package

Tags: packages, compiling

I am using the `lstlisting` package and the `semantic` package. Now whenever I write a `-` (minus) inside a lstlisting it disappears after the compilation. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
->  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

How do I get this fixed?

A [similar thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/minus-signs-vanish-with-listings-and-breqn-any-solutions) already exists, but the solutions shown there do not work for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `semantic` adds special treatment for some characters. In this example you can disable the behavior by `\mathligsoff`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}
\mathligsoff
\begin{lstlisting}
->
\end{lstlisting}
\mathligson
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The command can also be put into an init hook of `lstlistings`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{semantic}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\mathligsoff}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
->  
\end{lstlisting}
$->$ and \lstinline|->|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]