# Why do minus signs vanishes in listings typeset with matlab-prettifier?

Tags: listings, matlab

I am typesetting my MATLAB code with package `matlab-prettifier`. However, the `-` sign are gone. How can I get it back?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For MATLAB code
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstMakeShortInline[style=Matlab-editor]" % For inline shortcut

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]

>> a(2, 3)
ans =
    1.6606e-04

\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

P.S.: I am aware of the existence of [similar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/minus-signs-vanish-with-listings-and-breqn-any-solutions), but none of them works for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little what is it that goes wrong, because I get the mathmode minus `$-$`

Comment: @PierPaolo Weird. For me, the `-` is typeset as a space, and dollar signs are just dollar signs. I got `1.6606e$ $04`

Comment: @FarticlePilter: Did you try `mathescape=true` as option to `lstlisting` environment? By the way, your MWE does not contain `$-$` ;-)

Comment: @FarticlePilter It must be caused by some interaction with another package. Try adding, in this MWE, the packages that you load in your actual document (one by one), and see which one causes `-` to disappear.

Comment: @Jubobs Here we go. It turns out to be `breqn`.

Comment: @FarticlePilter Yes; I can confirm the problem. Incidentally, this happens with `listings`, irrespective of whether `matlab-prettifier` be used or not. Perhaps it would be best to reword your question accordingly, to make it more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listings` needs a 'hint' if the package should interprete `$-$` as math content otherwise it's taken verbatim. The hint is the `mathescape=true` option to the `lstlisting` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For MATLAB code
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstMakeShortInline[style=Matlab-editor]" % For inline shortcut

\begin{document}


Without

\begin{lstlisting}[,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]

>> a(2, 3)
ans =
    1.6606e-04

\end{lstlisting} 

With 

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]

>> a(2, 3)
ans =
    1.6606e-04

\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works now, except that as you may also see, the line in math mode seems in different style from MATLAB. Maybe there is an even more elegant way?

Comment: @FarticlePilter: The truth is, that you don't need `$...$` anyway, and in this case, the `mathescape=true` option is not needed at all. Do you have the latest `listings`/`matlab` packages?